# How can I better identify table conflicts inside my specified start and end endpoints in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, between, timetable

I have the following SQL statement to return rows where there are date conflicts for rows of a particular module:

```
SELECT e1.[id], e1.[start], e1.[end], e2.[id] AS Expr1, e2.[start] AS Expr2, e2.[end] AS Expr3
FROM ClassTimes AS e1 
INNER JOIN ClassTimes AS e2 ON e1.[id] < e2.[id]
WHERE (e1.[start] BETWEEN e2.[start] AND e2.[end])
AND (e1.[module] = @module) 
AND (e2.[module] = @module) 
OR  (e1.[module] = @module) 
AND (e2.[module] = @module) 
AND (e1.[end] BETWEEN e2.[start] AND e2.[end])
```

For some conflicts this works well such as the following rows in my database which will be returned:

```
id| start            | end              | module                 
----------------------------------------------------
1 | 30/02/2016 10:00 | 30/02/2016 11:00 | 1
2 | 30/02/2016 10:30 | 30/02/2016 11:30 | 1
```

But the issue I have is when I have a row with a start value that is is the equivalent end value for another row. I have shown this below for the value 30/02/2016 13:00.

```
id| start            | end              | module                 
----------------------------------------------------
3 | 30/02/2016 12:00 | 30/02/2016 13:00 | 1
4 | 30/02/2016 13:00 | 30/02/2016 14:00 | 1
```

How can I amend my sql statement to eliminate rows with these endpoints being returned?

Comment: The Join condition seems to be very strange. And as said jarlh, you have a bracket problems for the OR in your condition.

Comment: I had been working from a solution provided here: http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/finding-matching-conflicting-event-times-337399.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx).  Between is inclusive of the values in the range.

Use "<" and ">" instead and that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working for me now:

```
WHERE (e1.[module] = @module) 
AND (e2.[module] = @module) 
AND (e1.[end] > e2.[start]) 
AND (e1.[end] <= e2.[end]) 
OR  (e1.[module] = @module) 
AND (e2.[module] = @module) 
AND (e1.[start] >= e2.[start]) 
AND (e1.[start] < e2.[end])
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it you want to get all the rows where 2 modules are in the same time.

```
SELECT e1.[id], e1.[start], e1.[end], e2.[id] AS Expr1, e2.[start] AS Expr2, e2.[end] AS Expr3
FROM ClassTimes AS e1 
INNER JOIN ClassTimes AS e2 ON e1.[module] = e2.[module] AND e1.[id] < e2.[id]
WHERE e1.[module] = @module AND ((e1.[start] BETWEEN e2.[start] AND e2.[end])
    OR  (e1.[end] BETWEEN e2.[start] AND e2.[end]))
```